# How to call @Service method from @Component

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a component that I would like to call a service method from.  When I try to call nothing happens. The service method is completablefuture method that calls a rest api.  Could this have anything to do with it?

I've tried calling it from different classes and it works. Only this class is an issue.

Snippet of the class I'm calling it from:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Reader{  

///and other variable declarations used

@Autowired
private AsyncServices aService;


public void StartAsync() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

 Runnable task = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
   try {
    StartInventory();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.print("start inventory thread could not start: 
 "+ex.getLocalizedMessage());}
            }
        };
        Runnable task2 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StartTCPClient();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.print("start tcpclient thread could not start: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        tcpClientThread = new Thread(task2, "TCPClientThread");
       tcpClientThread.setDaemon(true);
        tcpClientThread.start();




      inventoryThread = new Thread(task, "InventoryThread");
        inventoryThread.setDaemon(true);
        inventoryThread.start();   

public void StartInventory() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, ParseException{
```

......

```
 //calling the method in @service class   
  aService.findVehicle(rfidtag);    

}

   code for service:
@Service
public class AsyncServices {   
private final RestTemplate appRestTemplate;

@Autowired
public AsyncServices(RestTemplateBuilder builder){
    this.appRestTemplate=builder.build();
}

@Async
 @Transactional
public CompletableFuture<BmwvehicleTest> findVehicle(String rfidtag) throws InterruptedException{
    log.info("trying to find a vehicle test by rfidtag"+ rfidtag);
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity <BmwvehicleTest> entity = new HttpEntity <BmwvehicleTest>(headers);
      BmwvehicleTest results=appRestTemplate.exchange("http://localhost/tag/"+rfidtag, HttpMethod.GET, entity, BmwvehicleTest.class).getBody();
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);


}
```

I expect to be able to get the result from the service method which is getting results from a rest api.

Comment: You've left out the declaration and injection of the service into the component. The code you provided wouldn't compile because aService isn't a declared variable.

Comment: I omitted it in my code by mistake.  Adding it in now. @AdamBates

Comment: I see a service called AServices with no parent but the service being injected is of type AsyncServices, are there supposed to be the same? Also, you're calling a hello method but you've omitted the definition of the method. Please use code that compiles otherwise it's difficult to know what exactly could be causing the issue.

Comment: @AdamBates Yes I fixed the typos in my code.